# chkrootkit unable to execute by shell

Tags: centos, chkrootkit

I installed `chkrootkit` with yum (CentOS 6.5) server with plesk 12.5
but I'm unable to execute it.

```
[root@~]# chkrootkit
-bash: chkrootkit: command not found
[root@~]#
```

I cannot locate the application, but yum says it's installed.

Answer (score 1):

Locate the location of the script "chkrootkit" and execute the script with its full path. To find the path :

```
whereis chkrootkit
```

or

```
rpm -ql chkrootkit |grep bin
```